# SimpleSAMLphp send SLO request to remote IDP Okta

Tags: php, saml-2.0, simplesamlphp

So i need to send to an OKTA IDP a SLO request from my ServiceProvider make with SimpleSAMLphp.

I have try the logout function of SimpleSAMLphp, but they only logout on the ServiceProvider not on my IDP...

The code used :

```
require_once('/var/www/service_provider/simplesamlphp/lib/_autoload.php');
$as = new SimpleSAML_Auth_Simple('default-sp'); 
$as->logout();
```

I try to add in parameter to logout() function the SLO url of my IDP but missing some parameters in the request and no documentations on how to generate this missing parameters...

Thanks for help!

Best regards,

**EDIT :**

I put my authsources config:

```php
'default-sp' => [
        'saml:SP',
        'entityID' => null,
        'idp' => 'http://www.okta.com/ID',
        'discoURL' => null,
        'privatekey' => 'sp.pem',
        'certificate' => 'sp.crt',
        'sign.logout' => true,
        'sign' => [
            'logout' => true
        ]
    ],
```

EDIT:

The IDP metadata:

```
$metadata['http://www.okta.com/randomString'] = array (
  'entityid' => 'http://www.okta.com/randomString',
  'contacts' => 
  array (
  ),
  'metadata-set' => 'saml20-idp-remote',
  'SingleSignOnService' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'Binding' => 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST',
      'Location' => 'https://okta/app/okta_test_1/randomString/sso/saml',
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
      'Binding' => 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect',
      'Location' => 'https://okta/app/okta_test_1/randomString/sso/saml',
    ),
  ),
  'SingleLogoutService' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'Binding' => 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST',
      'Location' => 'https://okta/app/okta_test_1/randomString/slo/saml',
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
      'Binding' => 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect',
      'Location' => 'https://okta/app/okta_test_1/randomString/slo/saml',
    ),
  ),
  'ArtifactResolutionService' => 
  array (
  ),
  'NameIDFormats' => 
  array (
    0 => 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified',
    1 => 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress',
  ),
  'keys' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'encryption' => false,
      'signing' => true,
      'type' => 'X509Certificate',
      'X509Certificate' => 'certValue',
    ),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So finaly the bug was i'll missed to start the session in the logout script. So SimpleSAMLPHP never found the current session, like suggest Patrick in is comment the isAuthenticated was always false.

So to correct the bug i had at the start of my logout script a

```php
session_start();
```

And it's works!

Answer (score 1):

You will need to first enable logout in the Okta app. This will require your service provider public cert since Okta wants logout requests to be signed.

Once you have enabled logout the SAML metadata for the Okta IdP changes to include the logout URLs. You will need to update the metadata you have in SSP so that SSP knows about Okta's logout url.

Lastly you need to enable signed logout messages from SSP. You do that with the `'sign.logout' => true` [option](https://simplesamlphp.org/docs/1.19/saml/sp.html) in your `authsources.php`

Comment: Thanks for your response but all of this be done, and OKTA does not log the sing logout request when i go in view logs, i see my login but not the logout.

Comment: I would use [SAML tracer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/saml-tracer/) plugin in your browser to debug. If your SP is not sending a SAML logout request to Okta IdP then it usually means SSP doesn't not think the IdP supports SLO, which implies the metadata it has for the IdP does not list the SLO endpoints.

Comment: I will try this plugin tomorow, but the SLO was present in the metadata of my IDP in the SSP.

Comment: i have clear my IDP metadata, to take the last (same of the previous), and check the ```'sign.logout' => true,
  'sign' => [
   'logout' => true
  ]``` was present in my authsources for my 'default-sp', and set the 'idp' in authsource in the idp target.

But still not working..

Comment: Could you log in as the SSP admin and view the metadata (it’s a php array) that SSP has for the IdP and add it in your question?

Comment: i have add the array of metadata for the IDP taked from the SSP admin

Comment: Do you have a valid SSP session when you call `logout()`?  You can use `isAuthenticated()` to check.  Can you also enable debug logging and show SSP log lines from when you perform the log out.

Comment: You got something interessting in fact i'll trie isAuthenticated before the logout, and it return always false. This line are in the log : Session: 'default-sp' not valid because we are not authenticated.

Comment: @Patrick Hello Patrick, can we talk in private about simplesamlphp config job? (criscalleo at gmail com)