# Implement Logout on Simplesamlphp

Tags: php, simplesamlphp

I'm new to this SimpleSamlPhp. I setup the SimpleSamlPhp as requirement from 3rd party for SSO. We've exchanged the metadata. For now, I can successfully login through the SSO, but I can't figure out how to logout. I have tried some suggestions from the internet but still fail. After logout, I'm still able to access the page. The problem is, it seems the cookies not cleared when I run this code:

```
    $as = new SimpleSAML_Auth_Simple('default-sp');
    $as = \SimpleSAML\Session::getSessionFromRequest();
    
    $as->logout(array(
    'ReturnTo' => '[3rd party home page]',
    'ReturnStateParam' => 'LogoutState',
    'ReturnStateStage' => 'MyLogoutState',
    ));
    SimpleSAML_Session::getSessionFromRequest()->cleanup();
```

Here is my setup:

**saml20-idp-remote.php**

```
    $metadata['https://[mydomain]/simplesaml/saml2/idp/metadata.php'] = [
        'metadata-set' => 'saml20-idp-remote',
        'entityid' => 'https://[mydomain]/simplesaml/saml2/idp/metadata.php',
        'SingleSignOnService' => [
            [
                'Binding' => 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect',
                'Location' => 'https://[mydomain]/simplesaml/saml2/idp/SSOService.php',
            ],
        ],
        'SingleLogoutService' => [
            [
                'Binding' => 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect',
                'Location' => 'https://[mydomain]/simplesaml/saml2/idp/SingleLogoutService.php',
            ],
        ],
        'certData' => '[somerandomkey]',
        'NameIDFormat' => 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient',
        'contacts' => [
            [
                'emailAddress' => 'myemail@gmail.com',
                'contactType' => 'technical',
                'givenName' => 'myname',
            ],
        ],
    ];
```

**saml20-sp-remote.php**

```
    $metadata['https://[3rdparty domain]/module.php/saml/sp/metadata.php/default-sp'] = [
        'entityid' => 'https://[3rdparty domain]/module.php/saml/sp/metadata.php/default-sp',
        'contacts' => [
            [
                'contactType' => 'technical',
                'givenName' => 'Administrator',
                'emailAddress' => [
                    'support@3rdpartydomain.com',
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'metadata-set' => 'saml20-sp-remote',
        'AssertionConsumerService' => [
            [
                'Binding' => 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST',
                'Location' => 'https://[3rdparty domain]/module.php/saml/sp/saml2-acs.php/default-sp',
                'index' => 0,
            ],
            [
                'Binding' => 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:profiles:browser-post',
                'Location' => 'https://[3rdparty domain]/module.php/saml/sp/saml1-acs.php/default-sp',
                'index' => 1,
            ],
            [
                'Binding' => 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Artifact',
                'Location' => 'https://[3rdparty domain]/module.php/saml/sp/saml2-acs.php/default-sp',
                'index' => 2,
            ],
            [
                'Binding' => 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:profiles:artifact-01',
                'Location' => 'https://[3rdparty domain]/module.php/saml/sp/saml1-acs.php/default-sp/artifact',
                'index' => 3,
            ],
        ],
        'SingleLogoutService' => [
            [
                'Binding' => 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect',
                'Location' => 'https://[3rdparty domain]/module.php/saml/sp/saml2-logout.php/default-sp',
            ],
            [
                'Binding' => 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:SOAP',
                'Location' => 'https://[3rdparty domain]/module.php/saml/sp/saml2-logout.php/default-sp',
            ],
        ],
    ];
```

**authsources.php**

```
    'default-sp' => [
       'saml:SP',
       'entityID' => 'https://[3rdparty domain]/module.php/saml/sp/metadata.php/default-sp',
       'idp' => 'https://[mydomain]/simplesaml/saml2/idp/',
       'discoURL' => null,
    ],
```

I'm guessing, I make some wrong setup in this authsources.php, but I don't know which one, cause I'm still very very new to this saml. I need your help guys, please bear with me.
Thanks.

Comment: There is way to force reauthentication, check this SO thread : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44786747/saml-is-it-possible-to-force-user-to-go-through-login-process-even-when-user-ha

Comment: Hi, I've tried to add 'ForceAuthn' => true to authsources.php, but it seems to have no effect.

Comment: 1) If you are the SP, then you do not need `saml20-sp-remote.php`. That file contains SAML metadata about other SPs. You only need IdP metadata. 2) The `idp`  entityId you listed from `authsources.php` does not match the one in `saml20-idp-remote.php`. Perhaps a copy-n-paste error.  3) The previous points are unrelated to SLO.  Which cookies aren't being cleared? You apps or SSPs? Do you get redirect to the IdP during logout?  Do you even have a session when calling logout (See https://stackoverflow.com/a/73414965/54396)?